# Cookie base authentication looses session in IE8

Tags: cookies, internet-explorer-8

hoping someone from the community can assist with an issue that is perplexing me at the moment.

a website uses client-side authorization: once a user authenticates, a cookie is set and then cookie is used to validate the user. 3 cookies are used by the website: "auth" - contains an authorization token used to validate the session. "sess" - contains session information used by the webapp. "authto" - a "timeout" cookie that contains date/time information relating to client-side session expiry (effective a timestamp).

the web app has been working pretty well over the last few months, but for some strange reason, today IE8 is unable to maintain a session. I can log in, and once logged in, the moment I navigate, i am logged out.  Only IE8 is doing this (the oldest version of IE we support). chrome, firefox, safari, opera and >=ie9 all work as expected. ie8 stopped working. today. on the same app that was working yesterday.

any ideas?

Comment: it looks like IE is not storing any session cookies.

Answer (score 0):

We are using typekit. For some reason, it's stopped IE8 from storing all session cookies.

If we disable typekit, the web app works normally.